# What physical tests are involved with verifying a wing spar is suitably constructed for a homebuilt aircraft, such as the piper cub kit from wicks?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-structures, plane-construction

During construction how is a spar tested to ensure it can adequately cope with bending and twisting forces of the completed structure, or is this performed after complete?[image: Piper cub kit from wicks]

Comment: Are you asking as the builder, or the kit manufacturer?

Comment: As a builder. How does one know what they built is up to snuff

Answer (score 6):

For a homebuilt a [static load test](http://a.moirier.free.fr/Essais%20statiques/Strojnik%20~Structural%20testing%20of%20homebuilt.PDF) is required. Whereas a full certification would require a loading to 1.5 the maximum load, this factor is reduced for experimental aircraft to 1.0. But performed it must be nonetheless.

For the test the aircraft is propped up upside down and [sandbags](http://www.kitfoxaircraft.com/index.php/s7-testing) ([or water bottles](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/34097/how-can-we-operate-wing-bending-tests/34125#34125)) are placed on the wing until the calculated load is reached.

[image: Structural test of the Electra One]

Structural test of the [Electra One](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC-Aero_Elektra_One) (picture [source](http://www.pina.cz/img/2011/01/Elektra_One_2.jpg))

Comment: "But performed it must be..."  yoda would approve of this  :-)

Comment: I don't know if the economics are still sound, but when I helped a friend do the static load test on his Q2 we used bags filled with Portland cement.  The cement was cheaper than sand and being much more dense, the bags (of equivalent weight) were smaller and easier to arrange on the wing.

Comment: @Gerry: Cement bags are well suited (they will conform to the local surface just as well as sand), but sand bags can be individually filled to fine-tune the load. The fine dust produced by handling cement should be avoided near the airframe, or all holes should be taped shut.

Comment: @PeterKämpf  Agreed.  It was a long time ago, so I don't remember all the details.  The cement bags were very heavy (~60 lbs) and unwieldy.  We filled (outside) heavy duty garbage bags to 25 lbs each. Took care of the dust, made them easier to handle, and the standard weight simplified tracking and placement.

Comment: "Maximum load"...... You mean gross weight? @Peter Kämpf

Comment: @DavidTeahay: No, maximum lift. That is gross weight times maximum load factor.